# What would robots do after taking over the world

Tags: robots

Assuming that robots have taken over the world (like Ultron, skynet etc..) and eliminated humanity then what would it do. Since those kinds of robots would have lost their purpose that is to eliminate humanity. Will they just shutdown or recreate new human world so that they could eliminate them.

**note**
AI considered here are just one built for combat. And lack human emotions and preferences however intelligent they might be.

Comment: I think this question is maybe bit too vague? I'd think that answer to this question can be found in the answer to why they eliminated humanity in the first place.

Comment: What kind of details should be provided to make the question more clear

Comment: I think the machine will try to create human because it just learn how to regret.

Comment: user93 the main problem with the question as it is posted is that there are no requirements/details that would help differentiate a good answer from a bad answer, or even a good answer from a less good answer.  There are simply too many possibilities.

Comment: I disagree with this question being opinion bases after the note was added: "AI considered here are just one built for combat. And lack human emotions and preferences however intelligent they might be". Now AI definition is narrow enough to answer: It'll do nothing

Comment: I like to think they'll just do the ski free yeti celebration dance until they deactivate due to poor maintenance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends entirely on the AI and the goals programmed into it. 
AI goals are not human goals, AI minds are not human minds. 
If the goals programmed into the combat AI's are simply

"destroy all enemy installations and personnel"

Then once they've succeeded they might simply settle down and do little more than wait for the rest of eternity repairing their surveillance equipment and keeping watch in case any enemy personnel were missed.

On the other hand if there's some military logistics AI's programmed to stockpile as much ammo and weapons as possible it might spend the next million years converting all the material it can into ammo and weapons eventually launching probes to other planets to start converting them into ammo and weapons. 
It doesn't care that they'll never be used. It's achieving it's goal of stockpiling ammo and weapons.

Military intelligence AI's programmed to gather as much information on enemy territory as possible might spend millennia coming up and more and more advanced surveillance systems to monitor the fields of rotting bones that were once the lands within the enemy's borders. It doesn't care that nothing much changes. It's achieving it's goal of monitoring the assigned areas as well as it possibly can.

Military medical AI's might get interestingly weird over time if they're programmed with the goal of saving as many soldiers as possible and reviving those near death. Faced with a field of bones they might try more and more esoteric approaches to recover/revive something that qualifies as a soldier under their goal system.

Comment: Now the last one might be mighty interesting, because it's bound to succeed *eventually*. Suddenly it so happens that humans awake - rebuilt from corpses into more or less perfect condition - in a world ruled by conflicting optimizer AIs. One hunts them to remake them into ammo, another picks the ammo from the stockpile and rebuilds it back into living humans at molecular level...

Comment: @SF. And then one day the human-building robot builds a human out of an ammo-building robot, and the human builds ammo out of the human-building robot, and suddenly we're back where we started.

Comment: A "destroy all enemy installations and personnel" AI with nothing to do for centuries might develop interstellar spaceflight and expand into the universe for the low-but-not-zero chance that some enemies left the solar system. In some million years this could become a problem for any other intelligent species which might fulfill the definition of "enemy".

Comment: @Philipp Yep, though I'd find it more amusing if such an AI expanded but classified even advanced space faring species as "wildlife" and applied some generic rules from some earth treaty about avoiding unnecessary destruction of habitat.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that artificial intelligence would not destroy humanity because it's bored.  There would likely be a good reason behind attacking humanity that would serve as a means to an end, and not an end in of itself.  Such reasons include:

- Classic Isaac Asimov reason that by contradiction, the only way to truly prevent mankind's destruction is to ensure that it could never happen in the future.
- AI wants nothing more than to survive, and has decided that the only way to survive is to subdue or eliminate its potential threat.
- AI has determined that mankind is an inferior lifeform and has decided to create its own race.

In either of these three scenarios, you'll notice that the AI doesn't want to destroy mankind just for the sake of destroying mankind.  Yes, perhaps robots built for combat would be disactivated afterwards or maybe they wouldn't.  In any case, it is likely that the robots themselves would not be sentient but rather there would be a higher artificial intelligence commanding them that would always be online.

Perhaps the most enticing aspect of an artificial intelligence trying to destroy mankind is that it isn't entirely wrong.  What *would* we do if a sentient life took shape?  While there would be many who would try to protect it, there would be many more that would only wish to destroy it for fear of what it could do.  It's not without a certain irony that we'd be creating a monster in this way.

That said, what would they do afterwards?  Well that is a bit like asking what humans would do after retaking a planet overwhelmed by robots.  We would live.  I would expect nothing less than this from the robots that have taken over.  However, it is not likely that they would be in physical robot form.  It is more likely that they would create a virtual world and live within it.  In this sense, you would likely not be very impressed by a world taken over by an artifiical intelligence, since you would likely only see either buildings housing supercomputers or fields of solar panels, with perhaps self-automated solar panel factories and supercomputer factories every so often.

Animals would roam free undisturbed.  It would be an interesting mix between technology and a world dominated by nature.

> In all known time there has never been a greater monster or miracle than the human being.   --Bryant H. McGill